# Code Analysis FXCop VSTS 2015 configuration

Tags: continuous-integration, code-analysis, azure-pipelines, fxcop

I am trying to configure code analysis task for CI inside an existing build definition. The code compiles well. I have configured code analysis to execute for minimum rules. However, I get the below error (Copied from console log).

```
Starting Code Analysis
Include file: d:\a\1\s\bin\d:\a\1\s\bin\SampleAppCICD.dll
/ruleset:+C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\Rule Sets\ManagedMinimumRules.ruleset /Summary /out:d:\a\1\s\codeanalysisresult.html /verbose /outXsl:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\xml\FxCopReport.xsl /applyoutXsl
Microsoft (R) FxCop Command-Line Tool, Version 14.0 (14.0.25420.1) X86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation, All Rights Reserved.
Loaded dataflowrules.dll...
Loaded designrules.dll...
Loaded globalizationrules.dll...
Loaded interoperabilityrules.dll...
Loaded maintainabilityrules.dll...
Loaded mobilityrules.dll...
Loaded namingrules.dll...
Loaded performancerules.dll...
Loaded portabilityrules.dll...
Loaded reliabilityrules.dll...
Loaded securityrules.dll...
Loaded securitytransparencyrules.dll...
Loaded usagerules.dll...
Rule set found at 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\Rule Sets\ManagedMinimumRules.ruleset'
System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: * Analysis was not performed; at least one valid rules assembly and one valid
Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: * Analysis was not performed; at least one valid rules assembly and one valid
System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: target file must be specified.
Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: target file must be specified.
System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: * 1 total analysis engine exceptions.
```

[image: Configuration Screen shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Files you specified in **File’s input box** is incorrect, it is based on **Build Directory** that you specified.

For example, the **SampleAppCICD.dll** path is `d:\a\1\s\bin\SampleAppCICD.dll` ($(build.sourcesDirectory) value is d:\a\1\s), then **Build Directory** input box: `$(build.sourcesDirectory)\bin`; **File’s** input box: `SampleAppCICD.dll`.